# UILabel long press recognition

Tags: ios, swift

Edit: Added the correct code into the code below. Now working.

I have a label that sits at the top of my game while its running. I want to be able to long press the label and it bring up the main menu. Right now when I long press the app crashes with the below error.

The error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[blocks1.ViewController
>   longTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101800000'
>   *** First throw call stack:

The basics of what I have:

```
var gameTopTitle = UILabel()

//this is all after my gameTopTitle is added to the screen
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTap))
gameTopTitle.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
gameTopTitle.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

and the function

```
    func longTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("Long tap")
    if sender.state == .ended {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
    }
    else if sender.state == .began {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.")
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
    }
}
```

Comment: try with #selector(self.longTap)

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: your welcome, I posted it as Answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this

```
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTap))
```

I hope this helps you